# Calculating the percentage to win

Tags: python

I am working on a program that will display a random winner depending on their percentage to win. Here's an algorithm that can help you better understand:

1. Ask multiple users for their names.
2. The program should ask if they need more players.
3. If they do, then add 3 more players. If not, continue on.
4. When done, calculate a random integer between the values of 0 - 100.
5. Display to the first player this number, along with the percentage they have to win, then the second, then the third, etc (The closer their number to 100 is a higher percentage)
6. Choose a random winner, people with higher percentages should be more likely to win.
7. Thank the users for playing the game, and ask if they would like to play again or exit.

**How would I determine an appropriate percentage by how close a random number is to 100?**

I understand some of this code may be irrelevant, but I wanted my question to make as much sense as possible by understanding the whole program - that helps you more.

Here is my code so far:

```
#Luck Draw#
#=========#
import time
import random

print("You will be given a number, the closer your number to 100, the higher the chance you win!")

print("Player 1, please input your name.")
player1 = input()

print("Player 2, please input your name.")
player2 = input()
print("Player 3, please input your name.")
player3 = input()

morePlayers = input("Would you like more players?")
morePlayers = morePlayers.upper()

if morePlayers == 'YES':
    print("Player 4, please input your name.")
    player4 = input()
    print("Player 5, please input your name.")
    player5 = input()
    print("Player 6, please input your name.")
    player6 = input()
    print("** Unfortunately this program does not support more than six players yet! **")
    time.sleep(2.5)

    time.sleep(0.75)
    print("Calculating...")
    time.sleep(3)
    player1num = random.randint(0,100)
    print(player1 + " Your number is:", str(player1num) + "! You have a percantage to win of: ")
    time.sleep(0.75)
    print("Calculating...")
    time.sleep(3)
    player2num = random.randint(0,100)
    print(player2 + " Your number is:", str(player2num) + "! You have a percantage to win of: ")
    time.sleep(0.75)
    print("Calculating...")
    time.sleep(3)
    player3num = random.randint(0,100)
    print(player3 + " Your number is:", str(player3num) + "! You have a percantage to win of: ")
    time.sleep(0.75)
    print("Calculating...")
    time.sleep(3)
    player4num = random.randint(0,100)
    print(player4 + " Your number is:", str(player4num) + "! You have a percantage to win of: ")
    time.sleep(0.75)
    print("Calculating...")
    time.sleep(3)
    player5num = random.randint(0,100)
    print(player5 + " Your number is:", str(player5num) + "! You have a percantage to win of: ")
    time.sleep(0.75)
    print("Calculating...")
    time.sleep(3)
    player6num = random.randint(0,100)
    print(player6 + " Your number is:", str(player6num) + "! You have a percantage to win of: ")

    print("And the winner is...")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("...")
    time.sleep(1)
    print(winner + "!")
else:
    print("Calculating...")
    player1num = random.randint(0,100)
    print(player1 + " Your number is:", str(player1num) + "! You have a percantage to win of: ")
    time.sleep(0.75)
    print("Calculating...")
    time.sleep(3)
    player2num = random.randint(0,100)
    print(player2 + " Your number is:", str(player2num) + "! You have a percantage to win of: ")
    time.sleep(0.75)
    print("Calculating...")
    time.sleep(3)
    player3num = random.randint(0,100)
    print(player3 + " Your number is:", str(player3num) + "! You have a percantage to win of: ")
```

Comment: Would the random number a player is given act as the odds that they have of winning? 

So for instance, Player 1 get's the number 80, so they should therefore have an 80 percent chance of winning, Player 2 get's the number 0, and will not win, Player 3 get's the number 20 and has a 20 percent chance of winning?

Comment: Well, you don't need any percentages to start with. And it's really a question to you: what do you want your rules to be? If the player with the biggest number wins, then you already have everything. If anybody who got more than, say N, wins, you need to introduce that constant and compare the values with it. If you want to split the prize proportionally then again, _proportionally to what_? Try to clarify what is it what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Firstly, Ivan. I would like my program to calculate an approximate percentage depending on the number. I don't know the rules myself so that's why I'm asking.
Secondly, Alf. Thank you for the in-depth explanation, however, have you got any ideas or rules that I could use to calculate this percentage?

Comment: your question makes no sense if you have 75/100 ... that effectively means 75% of randomly picked numbers will be less than your number, and only 25% will be higher than your number ...

Comment: Let me elaborate I see where the confusion may come.

Okay. So, lets say the user Jon gets the number 58, I want their percentage to be split depending on the other users numbers.

Jon = 58
Marie = 37
Bob = 19

Jon would have a higher chance of winning, but how would I GET Jons percentage? I am really confused myself, I just thought adding a percentage would have been a nice way to tell the players about their chances.

Comment: I think it might help to elaborate on how a winner is chosen first vs how to calculate the percentage.  In your example Jon gets 58, Marie gets 37 and Bob gets 19.  To determine your winner are you selecting a random number from 0 to 100, and using price is right rules? (Bob would win at 19 an under, Marie would win at 20 - 37 and Jon would win from 38 - 100 (100 because noone has the higher bid)

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is random sampling with probabilities assigned to each item. You will be wanting to make use of the numpy library.

Something like this might be useful for you.

```
import numpy as np
players = ["fred", "alice", "mary"]
probabilities = [0.2, 0.7, 0.1]     # probabilities of each player
winner = np.random.choice(players, p=probabilities)
```

Hope that helps.

Ronny